# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

I have a productive application on my server. It worked perfectly fine but now i get the error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'.
```

It's very strange because the application worked very well a week ago.

Since then i made some changes on the iptables but i don't know if that causes that issue.

I tried solution provided on [Stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111) but it didn't worked for me.

Does anyone have a idea how i can fix that error?

Kind regards, 
Toni

Comment: Tried `sudo iptables -F` and try connecting again? This will remove any changes made to iptables so make sure you have your changes saved before doing it. Also you could show what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

What is firewall you use in server: Ufw or Itables:
The first, With firewall ufw  you can allow port mysql with command:

```
sudo ufw allow from any[Maybe IP] to any port 3306
```

Second, With firewall Iptables you allow with command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.241.41 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT && /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

After you can check port with netstat and telnet from client:

```
netstat -tulpn |grep 3306
```